# Flutter: `setState()` when screen off, or how to detect if screen is on?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

**TLDR:** I have a problem that should be solved if there is answer to one of the below questions:

1. Is there a way I can detect if the screen is on e.g.

```dart
if (SCREEN IS ON) {
  setState(() {});  // i.e. update displayed widgets
}
```

2. Is there a way to call `setState()` so that is finishes when the screen is off?

**More details:**

I have an app that plays audio. When the screen is on, the widgets update via `setState()` (e.g. to display the progress of the audio). Nonetheless it would be nice to let a user turn off their screen to save battery - however if I call `setState()` when the screen is off, it seems that the app waits for the screen to be turned back on before finishing the `setState()` code.

Hence I am hoping to determine if I can detect and only call `setState()` when the screen is on, alternatively can I call `setState()` when the screen is off so that is completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to @mario-francois I got the following to work for me:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  bool screenOn = true;

  @override
  Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:// screen off/navigate away
      // this.screenOn = false;
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:  // screen on/navigate to
        this.screenOn = true;
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:  // screen off/navigate away
        this.screenOn = false;
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this for chatApp to track the app State. I wrap the MaterialApp. With some changes you could do what you want.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_stripe/flutter_stripe.dart';

import 'constants/credentials.dart';
import 'domain/repositories/my_user_repository.dart';

class AppLifeCycleManager extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final MyUserRepository myUserRepo;

  const AppLifeCycleManager(
      {Key? key, required this.child, required this.myUserRepo})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppLifeCycleManagerState createState() => _AppLifeCycleManagerState();
}

class _AppLifeCycleManagerState extends State<AppLifeCycleManager>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    widget.myUserRepo.setOnlineCustomer();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    // set the publishable key for Stripe - this is mandatory
    Stripe.publishableKey = pkTest;
  }

  @override
  Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);

    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        widget.myUserRepo.setInactiveCustomer();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        widget.myUserRepo.setOnlineCustomer();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        widget.myUserRepo.setInactiveCustomer();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        widget.myUserRepo.setInactiveCustomer();
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.myUserRepo.setInactiveCustomer();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! From your code I managed to get the following to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72847415/5179470

Comment: I'm glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

[mounted](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html) might be what you are looking for. Alternatively, you could check the [AppLifecycleState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState.html) by using [WidgetsBindingObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but [screen state](https://pub.dev/packages/screen_state) in the pub might be what you're looking for.